# How to find out the encryption method

Tags: encoding, encryption

If I have the original and encrypted string how can I find out the encryption method?
for example I have original string 0812388140 and the encoded one B2BCxW1tnHkzEfMfJM888Q==.

Comment: For secure crypto-algorithms, you just don't.

Comment: [determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3989/45523)

Answer (score 3):

If the encryption algorithm is secure (like any of the most supported ones is) you cannot: they are designed to make the encrypted text appear as random data, so none of them leaves a 'signature' that will hint you.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way: The cryptosystem is a "black box machine". You can put in a string, and you get out a string at the other end. You're not allowed to look inside. What you're asking is really *how can I tell the inner workings of the black box by looking at what comes out when a single string is fed to the box?* Clearly, you cannot do this.

Comment: Actually, many encryption algorithms are publicly described: the secret is not the way the plain text is encrypted, you are allowed to look inside since the only secret is the key.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find-out the algorithm by simply looking at the encrypted result.