# How to find out what method of encryption was used?

Tags: encryption

Both the encrypted and decrypted lines of text are available and the key is also known.

Knowing all these things, how would I find out what method was used to encrypt it in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried bruteforce? Encrypt/decrypt the text with every known method that you expect that might be the answer, then compare output with the other string and you have your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out the encryption method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538950/how-to-find-out-the-encryption-method)

Comment: This is also offtopic for StackOverflow. While it might be on-topic for security.stackexchange.com or crypto.stackexchange.com, they'll tell you the same thing that the linked duplicate question does: this isn't possible directly. You would need to do reverse engineering work on the encryptor or decryptor, explore "likely" solutions as CptBartender suggests, or use other clues in the data (particularly if you are able to generate many messages to an oracle). But there is no "turn a crank" kind of solution. It is detective work based on experience with crypto systems.